# jquery widget and visibility problem

Tags: jquery

I have a widget:

```
http://designer-depot.com/prob/
```

When clicking to tab2, the image is not visible. Its only visible when mouse over. What is my mistake in jquery or css coding.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You HTML-code and Javascript-code both look very bad...

Comment: Do you really have yo use this tab widget? JQuery UI provides a better one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: If you would be a very good coder, we seen the solution not word salad! It means that you are not very different from me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple, conflicting jQuery functions going on here. Looks like you've been experimenting with several different tutorials all at once.  Your tab navigation widjet is not even getting a chance to function, as this one is triggering first:

```
 $("#cnb li").mouseover(function(){
 $("#cnb li").removeClass("crn");
 $(this).addClass("crn");
 });
```

You could probably strip out everything else in your JS file and just use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#cnb li").click(function(){
 $("#cnb li").removeClass("crn");
 $(this).addClass("crn");
 });
});
```

Comment: @graphicdivine
Thank you very much for reply. I have updated my widget with your code. But no the problem is:
1- after page loading there is not any problem. all images in tab one and tab are visible.
2- when you click on tab1 text and then click on tab2, now the image on tab2 is unvisible! The problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!
The solution is changing second id to cnb2. Because the id maybe unique!
Thanks to jquery.com forum.